# Not able to run Karma with Webpack 3

Tags: webpack, karma-runner, karma-webpack

Am using webpack :3.8.1, karma:1.7.1 and karma-webpack:2.0.6 . When tried to run karma it shows **ERROR [preprocess]: Can not load "webpack", it is not registered!.**
Are these latest versions not compatible ? Should I do something on the config ?
Please let me know.

Regards
Santhosh